# How to retrieve the currently logged in user role name in textbox using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to retrieve the currently logged in user role name in textbox using vb.net ?

iam currently using

```
TextBox1.Text = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)
```

om page load event but it is highlighted by a blue line in visual studio 2008

Comment: user name or role name ? There could be multiple roles for user. For name, try HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: role name i want in textbox which user is login to my site .... to identify that the user which is logged into my site is in which role ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.Web.Security.Roles` class:

C#:

```
String[] roles = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```

VB:

```
Dim roles As String() = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser()
```

Comment: I m currently using vb.net !!

Comment: whatz wrong with this code ?

TextBox1.Text = Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)

Comment: `GetRolesForUser()` returns an array of Strings. Try following code instead: `textBox1.Text = String.Join(", ", System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser())`

Comment: roles is an array. You can set the TextBox text to the first element of the array.

Comment: Hi ..i m trying to create a GetUserRole in vb.net with the help of RoleProvider(Allowing to inherits only). but on <Authorize>  its not calling that function. but if do the same in using C# its working.Can you please provide vb.net example